# scaling up data series based on polynomial equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have yearly time series data starting from 1990 to 2100 AD (x-axis). The value for 1990 is 0 and 2100 is 700, and it's increasing in each year (but not linearly). Based on this series, I come up with a curve fitting third-order polynomial equation. Now, I want to get a new data series that follows similar pattern as the polynomial equation, but has a new value as 1000 in 2100 and has the same value in 1990 (which is 0). How can it be done?

Thanks in advance, it should be a simple concept and I really should know this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but here is one simple way. Let $f(x)$ be the third-order polynomial you found that has $f(1990)=0$ and $f(2100)=700$. Define

$$g(x)=\frac{10}{7}f(x)$$

Then we get $g(1990)=0$ and $g(2100)=1000$, as you wanted, and $g(x)$ is also a third-order polynomial.

Comment: That's great. Thanks! How about if  _g(1990)_ is not known, but we only know _g(2100) = 1000_? What would be a way to resolve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean you don't care what $g(1990)$ is, the above example still works. If you mean you want $g(1990)=a$ where $a$ is a known value, then define $g(x)=\frac{1000-a}{700}f(x)+a$.